Can I insulate this open air pipe in my basement?
I just bought this home in October and I live in the north east where it gets very cold in the winter. I have a 3 season sun room attached to my house and it seems like there’s a ventilation pipe that feeds into my basement. The problem is it has a very cold draft blowing in 30 degree air when I measure it with my food thermometer. Would there be any problem if I use fiberglass or rockwool insulation in the pipe? I’m worried about potential ventilation issues under the sunroom if I do this.
Edit: Here are some pictures


The home is heated with heat pumps so there is no combustion going on. The pipe vents directly under the sunroom.

Depends what the pipe/duct is supposed to be doing in the system of your entire house. Which is not at all clear from here at this level of detail.

A picture would help.  Insulating/wrapping the the outside of the pipe is okay, but for ventilation/air inlet for heating, you do not want anything in the pipe.

It looks like you've accidentally created duplicate accounts. See the [help] to get them merged, and you'll be able to edit/update your own posts more easily.
